# Entry Widget: Storing It In Variable

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-entry

I wanted to store data from Entry to an variable.
So I did this:

```
main = Tk()

main.title("Players Names")

var1 = StringVar()
var2 = StringVar()

Label(main, text="Player One: ").pack(side=LEFT)
e1 = Entry(main, textvariable=var1).pack(side=LEFT)
Label(main, text="Player Two: ").pack(side=LEFT)
e2 = Entry(main, textvariable=var2).pack(side=LEFT)

def enter():
    player1 = var1.get()
    player2 = var2.get()


def printIt():
    print player1
    print player2

Button(main, width=15, text="ENTER", command=enter).pack(side=LEFT)
Button(main, width=15, text="PRINT", command=printIt).pack(side=LEFT)

main.mainloop()
```

When I tried it...

...it printed nothing. What shall I do (except by putting the printIt function in enter function. I know this; i just want to store the data)?

Comment: player1 and player2 are defined inside the function `enter()`, and stayed into it

Answer (score 1):

`player1` and `player2` are local to the `enter()` function and therefore cannot be accessed outside of it. While you *could* make them global variables that can be referenced by any and all functions, globals are generally considered to be poor way to do things for a variety of reasons. (See [***Global Variables Are Bad***](http://wiki.c2.com/?GlobalVariablesAreBad) for a specifics about why it's probably a good idea to avoid them.)

One way to sidestep having to do that in Tkinter applications, is make your program more object-oriented and define the main window to be a subclass of its `Tkinter.Frame` widget. This is fairly easy to do and then you can then add as many additional attributes to it as needed and reference them from any of its methods via `self.xxx` without polluting the global namespace with a bunch of "stuff".

Here's what I mean (note I remove your `e1` and `e2` variables because they were both being assigned `None` (because that's what the `pack()` method returns). They weren't being used anywhere else, anyway, which is probably why you never noticed.

```
from Tkinter import *

class App(Frame):
    def __init__(self, title, master=None):
        Frame.__init__(self, master)  # initialize base class
        self.pack()
        self.master.title(title)

        self.var1 = StringVar()
        self.var2 = StringVar()

        Label(self, text="Player One: ").pack(side=LEFT)
        Entry(self, textvariable=self.var1).pack(side=LEFT)
        Label(self, text="Player Two: ").pack(side=LEFT)
        Entry(self, textvariable=self.var2).pack(side=LEFT)

        Button(self, width=15, text="ENTER", command=self.enter).pack(side=LEFT)
        Button(self, width=15, text="PRINT", command=self.printIt).pack(side=LEFT)

    def enter(self):
        self.player1 = self.var1.get()
        self.player2 = self.var2.get()

    def printIt(self):
        print(self.player1)
        print(self.player2)

app = App("Player's Names")
app.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

`player1` and `player2` are stored exclusively in the function as *local* variables, which means they can only be accessed *within* the function.

You should instead return the results:

```
def enter():
    return [var1.get(), var2.get()]

def printIt():
    print enter()[0], enter()[1]
```

or make them global variables by declaring them outside your functions which is probably simpler:

```
main = Tk()

main.title("Players Names")

var1 = StringVar()
var2 = StringVar()
player1 = None               # Global variable declaration
player2 = None

Label(main, text="Player One: ").pack(side=LEFT)
e1 = Entry(main, textvariable=var1).pack(side=LEFT)
Label(main, text="Player Two: ").pack(side=LEFT)
e2 = Entry(main, textvariable=var2).pack(side=LEFT)

def enter():
    global player1, player2
    player1 = var1.get()
    player2 = var2.get()


def printIt():
    global player1, player2
    print player1
    print player2

Button(main, width=15, text="ENTER", command=enter).pack(side=LEFT)
Button(main, width=15, text="PRINT", command=printIt).pack(side=LEFT)

main.mainloop()
```

Comment: it's mostly needed in `enter()` but it does no harm to double it inside the printIt

Comment: Oh jesus, how I hate global variables